# Answer with more votes than question has views?

Tags: bug, status-completed

[This question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/631/what-to-consider-when-deciding-on-2d-vs-3d-for-a-game)'s best answer has 37 upvotes, yet the question itself has only 33 views. Even if they were the same, surely not every person who viewed the question would upvote an answer?

Answer (score 3):

The view counter is cached while the vote count is "real time". Jeff has posted about this on one of the other new meta sites, but as there's half a dozen now I can't remember which one.

Answer (score 0):

I think there're bugs with the view counter, because it's also possible that an answered question have 0 views. It may also just be delayed like some of the other parts of the SO system. Reputation changes, for example are delayed between a site and it's meta and Area 51.